# `exit` inside parentheses doesn't exit script

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a simple question. Why does this not behave the way I think it would:

```
(echo "Test 1"; exit) && echo "Test 2"
```

...or...

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=2
[ $VAR1 == $VAR2 ] || (echo '$VAR1 does not equal $VAR2, exiting.'; exit)
echo -e 'Well, I\'m still alive yo!'
```

Running either of those two snippets will result in script execution continuing despite an explicit `exit` command.

Obviously the parentheses are affecting the command for some reason, my question is why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The parentheses execute their contents in a subshell, it is therefore the subshell that exits.

You would usually achieve the same effect either with another `&&` or using `{}` instead of `()`.

```
{ echo "Test 1"; exit; } && echo "Test 2"
```

Or

```
echo "Test 1" && exit && echo "Test 2"
```

Comment: How would one do the above without using said 'subshell'?

Comment: With this two examples given by Kevin, you will not use subshells ;)

Comment: Since it just cost me 5 minutes: the semicolon before the closing bracket is not optional - if it is missing, you will get a syntax error (presumably because bash thinks the } is an argument to the command before)

Answer (score 6):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

A command list embedded between parentheses runs as a subshell.

```
( command1; command2; command3; ... )
```

A code block between curly brackets does not launch a subshell.

```
{ command1; command2; command3; . . . commandN; }
```

In the first case the exit is being run by the sub shell which terminates and returns control to the invoking shell.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `( ... )` are executed in a subshell, so you just `exit` this shell. This approach should work better for you and it is easier to read an maintain for the next person to come along and open your script:

```
VAR1=1
VAR2=2
if [ $VAR1 == $VAR2 ] ; then
    echo -e "Well, I'm still alive yo!"
else
    echo "$VAR1 does not equal $VAR2, exiting."
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the parentheses and it should do what you want.

The parentheses are equivalent to putting their content into another shell script, where the `exit` just exits that shell script.

Comment: Removing the parenthesis alone won't work because of the operator's priority. The `||` will operate only in the first argument next to it. Try `BOOL || echo msg ; echo exit`, with `BOOL=true` and `BOOL=false`.